# PHP - Lowercase Multidimensional Array without Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code that is looking for $array2 in $array1.

The issue that I have is that I need to lowercase both arrays so the in_array matching works and this code operates as expected but $array1 is greater than 20k objects -- is there anyway to do the lowercase without losing the array structure and looping?

```
$array1 = array(code => 200, status => success,
        array(
        'email' => 'Example1223@sample.com',
        'status' => 'Pending'
        ),
       array(
        'email' => 'example123@sample.com',
        'status' => 'Approved: Printed & Cleared'
        ),
      array(
        'email' => 'example23@sample.com',
        'status' => 'Approved'
        ),
      array(
        'email' => 'Example22@sample.com',
        'status' => 'Approved: Printed & Cleared'
        ),
        );

$yourArray = array();
$array = array();
foreach ($array1 as &$array){

$yourArray[] = array_map('strtolower', $array);

}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($yourArray);

$array2 = array(
        'email' => 'example1223@sample.com',
        'status' => 'Pending'
        );   

$yourArray2 = array_map('strtolower', $array2);         

if(in_array($yourArray2 , $yourArray)) {
echo "match";
} else {
echo "no match";
}

echo "<pre>"; print_r($yourArray2);
```

Comment: note that `array_walk` and `array_walk_recursive` can both do this

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [preg_grep()](http://php.net/preg_grep) function:

```
preg_grep("/ONe/i", $yourArray2);
```

Comment: **Note:** This can be resource-intensive at 20k elements.

Comment: More resource-intensive than loop with 20k iterations? :) I don't think so

Comment: Actually, it *could* be, especially in memory consumption. [looping](https://3v4l.org/RgFp4/perf#output) vs [grep](https://3v4l.org/Sm82a/perf#output)